# is_single(); Question

Tags: pages, single

If a page would contain this code:

`<?php if( !is_single('') ): ?><div id="navtoggle"></div><?php endif; ?>`

But regardless of it would show the div navtoggle, would that mean the code makes WP think the page is a `posts` page?

If not, how can I make WP only show navtoggle on the homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at using [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) in wordpress. `is_single()` is the conditional tag for a single page, ie single.php.

For homepage, `is_home()` or `is_front_page()` should be use, depending on whether a front page is set in settings or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot I instead used `page_template` but that helped me look for other things!